# Error 1400: there is no such cell that satisfies criterias

Tags: excel, autofilter, vba

Here is the code to copy data after applying the filter.

```
  Sub read_excel_file(path_to_current_work_book As String, path_to_destination_workbook As String)

Dim work_book As Object
Dim destination_workbook As Object
Dim i, m As Integer
Dim array_of_account_numbers() As Variant
Dim array_of_debit_or_credits() As Variant
Dim current_sheets As Worksheet
Dim buf_rng As Range

array_of_account_numbers = Array("1400", "1401", "1402", "1403", "1410", "1411", "1412", "1413", "1414", "1420", "1421", "1422", "1423", "1424", "1430", "1440")
array_of_debit_or_credits = Array("10", "11", "20", "21")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Visible = True

Set work_book = Workbooks.Open(path_to_current_work_book)
Set destination_workbook = Workbooks.Open(path_to_destination_workbook)

destination_workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = "Debit(10,11)/Credit(20, 21)"
destination_workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2).Value = "Balance account number"
destination_workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 3).Value = "Currency code"
destination_workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 4).Value = "Resident"
destination_workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 5).Value = "Amount"
destination_workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 6).Value = "Date"

m = 2
For i = 1 To work_book.Worksheets.Count
    With work_book.Sheets(i)
        If (.UsedRange.Rows.Count > 1) Then
            .UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=array_of_debit_or_credits, Operator:=xlFilterValues
            .UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=array_of_account_numbers, Operator:=xlFilterValues
            m = destination_workbook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1
            .AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).Resize(.AutoFilter.Range.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy destination_workbook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & m)
        End If
    End With
Next i
work_book.Close savechanges:=False
destination_workbook.Close savechanges:=True
End Sub
```

It produces the following error (when the autofiltered range, excluding header, is empty): "Error 1400: there is no such cell that saticfies criterias".

```
.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).Resize(.AutoFilter.Range.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy destination_workbook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & m)
```

How can I handle this error?

Answer (score 3):

Set it to a range and then check if the range is `Nothing`

Try this (UNTESTED)

```
Dim Rng as Range

'
'~~> Rest of your code
'

On Error Resume Next
Set Rng = .AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).Resize(.AutoFilter.Range.Rows.Count _
          - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
    'rng.copy... blah blah
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tested your suggested solution. However, now the code produces the following error `424: Object required` in the following line:`If Not (Rng) Is Nothing Then`. Could you advise how to correct this error ?

Comment: I don't use `Option Explicit`, so I didn't define it.

Comment: @SiddharthRout I think we both over did this one (see my edit for why) I think this was a big case of [The Complicators Gloves](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Classic-WTF-The-Complicators-Gloves.aspx)

Comment: @mr.M: Could you please define it and try again?

Comment: @mr.M: You might also want to see `POINT 2` in [THIS](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/08/01/to-err-is-human/) link regarding `Option Explicit`

Comment: yeah, I have added option explicit. Now, I am waiting for the resutls )).

Comment: If you don't mind, I will check the results and tomorrow will answer your question.

Comment: @mr.M: Please take your time :)

Answer (score 0):

IF you Data is in List range (i think is has to be to autofilter) AND you only have one table/List on each sheet then instead of using With `work_book.Sheets(i)` use `With work_book.Sheets(i).ListObjects(1)`

Below is an untested sample of what I mean.

```
Sub read_excel_file(path_to_current_work_book As String, path_to_destination_workbook As String)

Dim work_book As Object
Dim destination_workbook As Object
Dim i, m As Integer
Dim array_of_account_numbers() As Variant
Dim array_of_debit_or_credits() As Variant
Dim current_sheets As Worksheet
Dim buf_rng As Range

array_of_account_numbers = Array("1400", "1401", "1402", "1403", "1410", "1411", "1412", "1413", "1414", "1420", "1421", "1422", "1423", "1424", "1430", "1440")
array_of_debit_or_credits = Array("10", "11", "20", "21")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Visible = True

Set work_book = Workbooks.Open(path_to_current_work_book)
Set destination_workbook = Workbooks.Open(path_to_destination_workbook)

destination_workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = "Debit(10,11)/Credit(20, 21)"
destination_workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2).Value = "Balance account number"
destination_workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 3).Value = "Currency code"
destination_workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 4).Value = "Resident"
destination_workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 5).Value = "Amount"
destination_workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 6).Value = "Date"

m = 2
For i = 1 To work_book.Worksheets.Count
    With work_book.Sheets(i).ListObjects(1)
        If (.Rows.Count > 1) Then
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=array_of_debit_or_credits, Operator:=xlFilterValues
            .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=array_of_account_numbers, Operator:=xlFilterValues
            m = destination_workbook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            If .Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
                .Range.Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1).copy destination_workbook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & m)
            End If
        End If
    End With
Next i
work_book.Close savechanges:=False
destination_workbook.Close savechanges:=True
End Sub
```

Actually I may be overthinking this whole thing try the code below, Its simply checking to see if the filtered range contains more then just the 1 header row, if it does then it will copy if it doesn't it skips it, I believe that is all you will need.

```
Sub read_excel_file(path_to_current_work_book As String, path_to_destination_workbook As String)

Dim work_book As Object
Dim destination_workbook As Object
Dim i, m As Integer
Dim array_of_account_numbers() As Variant
Dim array_of_debit_or_credits() As Variant
Dim current_sheets As Worksheet
Dim buf_rng As Range

array_of_account_numbers = Array("1400", "1401", "1402", "1403", "1410", "1411", "1412", "1413", "1414", "1420", "1421", "1422", "1423", "1424", "1430", "1440")
array_of_debit_or_credits = Array("10", "11", "20", "21")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Visible = True

Set work_book = Workbooks.Open(path_to_current_work_book)
Set destination_workbook = Workbooks.Open(path_to_destination_workbook)

destination_workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = "Debit(10,11)/Credit(20, 21)"
destination_workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2).Value = "Balance account number"
destination_workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 3).Value = "Currency code"
destination_workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 4).Value = "Resident"
destination_workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 5).Value = "Amount"
destination_workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 6).Value = "Date"

m = 2
For i = 1 To work_book.Worksheets.Count
    With work_book.Sheets(i)
        If (.UsedRange.Rows.Count > 1) Then
            .UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=array_of_debit_or_credits, Operator:=xlFilterValues
            .UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=array_of_account_numbers, Operator:=xlFilterValues
            m = destination_workbook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            If (.AutoFilter.Range.Rows.Count > 1) Then
                .AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).Resize(.AutoFilter.Range.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).copy destination_workbook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & m)
            End If
        End If
    End With
Next i
work_book.Close savechanges:=False
destination_workbook.Close savechanges:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you explaine, what does the `.ListObjects(1)` mean?

Comment: `.ListObjects` Represents a collection of all tables on a worksheet. So, `.ListObjects(1)` simply selects the first table in your worksheet, IF there is only one table per worksheet then it should be the one you are trying to work with. So instead of working with every cell on the worksheet (`UsedRange`) now we are only working with the actual data itself.

Comment: @mr.M Just updated my anser by only adding 2 lines to your original code to handle when your filter returns no results.

Comment: I have tested this solution before posting. It gives me the same error, as in the name of the topic.

Comment: @mr.M So did my first code (has been updated since original post) not work? what issue did you have with it?

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work. That solution gave me an error `Error 1400: there is no such cell that satisfies criterias`, on line `.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).Resize(.AutoFilter.Range.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).copy destination_workbook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & m)`

Comment: @mr.M That is my second sample I asked about my first Sample. The one using the ListObject and the range of the listobject opposed to using the entire sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code that produces desired results. I believe, there is some room for improvement for this code and I will appreciate if someone corrects it. I would like to thank  user2140261 and  SiddharthRout for giving me useful advises as well as sharing their code.

```
  Sub extractInformationFromExcelFiles()
Dim path_to_folder As String
Dim path_to_final_file As String
Dim path_to_current_file As String
Dim objfso As Object
Dim objfolder As Object
Dim obj_sub_folder As Object
Dim objfile As Object
Dim final_workbook As Workbook

path_to_folder = ""
path_to_final_file = ""

Set objfso = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
Set objfolder = objfso.getfolder(path_to_folder)

For Each obj_sub_folder In objfolder.subfolders
    For Each objfile In obj_sub_folder.Files
        path_to_current_file = path_to_folder & obj_sub_folder.name & "\" & objfile.name
        On Error Resume Next
        readExcelFile path_to_current_file, path_to_final_file
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next objfile
Next obj_sub_folder
Set final_workbook = Workbooks.Open(path_to_final_file)
End Sub

Sub readExcelFile(path_to_current_work_book As String, path_to_destination_workbook As String)

Dim work_book As Object
Dim destination_workbook As Object
Dim i, m As Integer
Dim array_of_account_numbers() As Variant
Dim array_of_debit_or_credits() As Variant
Dim current_sheets As Worksheet
Dim buf_rng As Range

array_of_account_numbers = Array("1400", "1401", "1402", "1403", "1410", "1411", "1412", "1413", "1414", "1420", "1421", "1422", "1423", "1424", "1430", "1440")
array_of_debit_or_credits = Array("10", "11", "20", "21")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Visible = True

Set work_book = Workbooks.Open(path_to_current_work_book)
Set destination_workbook = Workbooks.Open(path_to_destination_workbook)

destination_workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = "Debit(10,11)/Credit(20, 21)"
destination_workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2).Value = "Balance account number"
destination_workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 3).Value = "Currency code"
destination_workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 4).Value = "Resident"
destination_workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 5).Value = "Amount"
destination_workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 6).Value = "Date"
destination_workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 7).Value = "Bank name under NBU classification"

m = 2
For i = 1 To work_book.Worksheets.Count
    With work_book.Sheets(i)
        If (.UsedRange.Rows.Count > 1) Then
            .UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=array_of_debit_or_credits, Operator:=xlFilterValues
            .UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=array_of_account_numbers, Operator:=xlFilterValues
            m = destination_workbook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1
            If (.AutoFilter.Range.Rows.Count > 1) Then
            On Error Resume Next
                .AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).Resize(.AutoFilter.Range.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy destination_workbook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & m)
            On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        End If
    End With
Next i
work_book.Close savechanges:=False
destination_workbook.Close savechanges:=True
End Sub
```